# What does this mean and why does it not give me an answer? "If given, shape of x must be 1-d or the same as y"

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to model a simple integral as shown below

```
import numpy as np
import math
from numpy import math
import scipy

x = 0.5
y = 0.5

def f1( theta ):
    q = 2 * theta
    return(
        ( q / ( 2 * np.pi ) ) * 
        ( ( x + np.sin( theta ) * np.sin( theta )  - 
        ( y - np.cos( theta ) ) * np.cos( theta ) /
        ( (x + np.sin(theta) )**2 + 
        ( y - np.cos( theta ) )**2 ) )
        )

theta=np.array([0,2*np.pi])
I1 = f1(theta)
from scipy.integrate import simps
U = simps(I1,x)
print(U)
```

I expect to get a value but all I get is this:

```
ValueError: If given, shape of x must be 1-d or the same as y.
```

I'm kind of new to python so I'm still trying to understand what the errors mean.

Comment: Can you check you parenthesis in `f1`. Something's missing.

Comment: What is it, that you actually want to do? Did you read the [Doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.simps.html) ? `Scipy.integarate.simps` integrates over a list of points assuming equidistant knots. If this is not the case you may give the positions as second argument, which is the `...or same as y` part of the error message, as you only provide a number. Moreover, your list has only two points, which is probably not what you want. Do you want something like `F(x) = int f(s) ds from zero to x`?

Comment: I'm just trying to perform this integral which will help lead me to doing the rest of my project. Just looking for a function that just performs a simple integral. Again I'm kind of new at this so sorry if the answer may seem obvious.

Comment: Ok I got it to work. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Chris, happy to read that it is now working for you. Don't worry about the obvious answer, but looking at the error message it actually was. It seems you are starting with Python, so see you around , I guess. Cheers.